# Sum of Sine function of squared angle

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry, summation

Today I found in an IG that the identities hold:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\sin\frac{2\pi k^2}{n} = \frac{\sqrt n}{2}\left(1+\cos\frac{n\pi}{2}-\sin\frac{n\pi}{2}\right)$$

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\cos\frac{2\pi k^2}{n} = \frac{\sqrt n}{2}\left(1+\cos\frac{n\pi}{2}+\sin\frac{n\pi}{2}\right)$$

tested in wolframalpha, it is correct when n=100 https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sum%5B+Sin%5B2+k%5E2+Pi+%2F+100%5D%2C+%7Bk%2C1%2C100%7D%5D+-+Sqrt%5B100%5D%2F2+%281%2BCos%5B100+Pi%2F2%5D+-+Sin%5B100+pi+%2F+2%5D%29 . But I have no idea about the validity. I have tried product-and-sum identity, Bernoulli's method ($\int_{k-1}^k x^p \text dx = (p-1)$-th degree polynomial of $k$), and Taylor series which requires Faulhaber's Formula,  none succeeded.

Is there any way to derive this identities?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_Gauss_sum

Comment: The links out of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1891991) may also help.